# Why can't I create Azure VMs with Terraform anymore?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-network, terraform-provider-azure

I have been using Terraform for some time to deploy VMs on Azure. It has always worked well, but today I have found it will timeout after 10 minutes when trying to deploy a vnet, which has never happened before. Here's the log:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: 1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_network.vnet: network.VirtualNetworksClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=200 -- Original Error: Long running operation terminated with status 'Failed': Code="InternalServerError" Message="An error occurred."
```

I first thought it was a Terraform or `azurerm` plugin error, so I tried several combinations (terraform 0.11.3/azurerm 1.1.1, terraform 0.10.6/azurerm 0.3.3, etc.). I got the same problem with all of them. I can create a VM from the Azure portal with no problem, so I guess the problem will be in Terraform or the Azure API Terraform is using under the hood. In any case I don't know how else to debug this.

Here's the terraform template I'm using:

```
# Configure Azure provider
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "..."
  client_id       = "..."
  client_secret   = "..."
  tenant_id       = "..."
}

# create a resource group if it doesn't exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
    name = "a132rg"
    location = "ukwest"
}

# create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    name = "tfvnet"
    address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
}

# create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
    name = "tfsub"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
    address_prefix = "10.0.2.0/24"
    #network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id}"
}

# create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "ip" {
    name = "tfip"
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    public_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
    domain_name_label = "a132"

    tags {
        environment = "staging"
    }
}

# create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "ni" {
    name = "tfni"
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"

    ip_configuration {
        name = "ipconfiguration"
        subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.subnet.id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "static"
        private_ip_address = "10.0.2.5"
        public_ip_address_id = "${azurerm_public_ip.ip.id}"
    }
}

# create storage account
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
    name = "0fda935368315bd1a5f5560e"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    location = "ukwest"
    account_replication_type = "LRS"
    account_tier = "Standard"

    tags {
        environment = "staging"
    }
}

# create storage container
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storagecont" {
    name = "vhd"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    storage_account_name = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.name}"
    container_access_type = "private"
    depends_on = ["azurerm_storage_account.storage"]
}



# create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
    name = "a132vm"
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.ni.id}"]
    vm_size = "Standard_A6"

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer = "UbuntuServer"
        sku = "16.04-LTS"
        version = "latest"
    }

    storage_os_disk {
        name = "myosdisk"
        vhd_uri = "${azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.storagecont.name}/myosdisk.vhd"
        caching = "ReadWrite"
        create_option = "FromImage"
    }

    os_profile {
        computer_name = "a132"
        admin_username = "..."

        admin_password = "..."

    }


}
```

Comment: can you pull out the real error? you can also try using [this](https://github.com/Azure/terraform-test) docker image to test terraform with azure (or some other image).

Comment: @4c74356b41 What do you mean by real error? That's the error I get from Terraform, I can't access the error message from Azure as far as I know. I'll give a go to the docker image in a moment, thanks!

Comment: well, why cant you access Azure error? login to the portal and take a look for yourself

Comment: I am also seeing this issue/

Comment: This seems to be affecting West US and West Europe only.

Comment: This is also happening with az cli and azure's AzureRM powershell.

Comment: @GeoffreyGrosenbach Based on my understanding, Azure API maybe change, when creating VNet, sunbnet is required. See my answer, this works on ukwest.

Comment: @MattBrinkman When you create a VNet, subnet is required, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a VNet, you need create a subnet in it. See this [link:VirtualNetworkPropertiesFormat object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks#VirtualNetworkPropertiesFormat). So, you need modify you tf file like below:

```
# create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
    name = "tfvnet"
    address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    location = "ukwest"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    ##You need create a subnet in VNet.
    subnet {
        name = "subnet1"
        address_prefix = "10.0.3.0/24"

    }
}

# create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
    name = "tfsub"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
    virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
    address_prefix = "10.0.2.0/24"
    #network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id}"
}
```

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/terraform-create-complete-vm).

Comment: I test in my lab, I modify your example like [this](https://gist.github.com/Walter-Shui/b53f8e30cf61f38bbeb721b9dc359702), this works for me fine.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot :) I'm slightly confused as to what the name and the address prefix are different in the vnet reference to the subnet and the subnet it self. Why is one "tfsub" and the other "subnet1"? Shouldn't we use ${} terraform references?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT If this is true, can you explain why I was able to create vnets in other regions (using both az cli and pwoershell) *without* creating subnets?  (I provided screenshots demonstrating this to Azure support last evening.)  I was also able to create  vnet without a subnet in West US this morning.

Answer (score -2):

The issue is currently being mitigated. Creation of VNET is possible via Portal for those regions where they can't be created via CLI or PowerShell.

Comment: No, it is not true. The root reason is when OP create VNet, he did not contain subnet. It is required. I test Azure CLI. It works fine for me. `az network vnet create \
--name TestVNet \
--resource-group TestRG \
--location centralus \
--address-prefix 192.168.0.0/16 \
--subnet-name FrontEnd \
--subnet-prefix 192.168.1.0/24`. Yes, I test it in ukwest.